# passing GUID from CRM on premise to SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I have uploaded report to CRM which I created in SSRS, when I go into CRM and then run it from Report section it runs successfully, only thing is it's looking for GUID in order to show reports with value.

I want to automate this somthing like whenever I go to each client Profile in CRM and click on run reports it should fetch it's GUID and pass it to that report as parameter and show the report.

Please help.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531099.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [move/access cleint deatils SSRS report in CRM client level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628155/move-access-cleint-deatils-ssrs-report-in-crm-client-level)

Comment: It's half a same , because I already solved half issue. Now just looking for passing parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

1) change your report's datasource to embedded and then add button to the ribbon in Dynamics CRM( see following link)

http://mahadeomatre.blogspot.ca/2015/04/run-report-from-custom-ribbon-button.html?_sm_au_=iVV7VjqJnWZTNR0P